# Devops yaml string array not recognized when passed as part of complex object type parameter and coalesced with another object

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

You can loop through and print the strings in an array passed as a parameter to an Azure Devops Yaml Pipeline Template. You can also loop through a string array passed as part of a complex object, or coalesced with another array - but not both.

Below I have 2 working examples and then the one that crashes.

### Working example #1

##### azure-deploy.yml:

```
extends:
  template: azure-deploy-template.yml
  parameters:
    complexObject:
    - drink: 'water'
      foods:
      - 'apple'
      - 'banana'
```

##### azure-deploy-template.yml:

```
parameters:
- name: complexObject
  type: object

jobs:
- job: TestJob
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

  steps:
  - ${{ each o in parameters.complexObject }}:
    - ${{ each f in o.foods }}:
      - script: echo '${{convertToJson(f)}}'
      - script: echo '${{f}}'
```

##### outputs:

```
"apple"
apple
"banana"
banana
```

### Working example #2:

##### azure-deploy.yml:

```
extends:
  template: azure-deploy-template.yml
  parameters:
    animals: 
    - 'cat'
    - 'dog'
    complexObject:
    - drink: 'water'
    foods:
    - 'apple'
    - 'banana'
```

##### azure-deploy-template.yml

```
parameters:
- name: animals
  type: object
- name: complexObject
  type: object
- name: foods
  type: object

jobs:
- job: TestJob
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

  steps:
  - ${{ each o in parameters.complexObject }}:
    - ${{ each f in coalesce(parameters.foods, parameters.animals) }}:
      - script: echo '${{convertToJson(f)}}'
      - script: echo '${{f}}'
```

##### outputs:

Same as #1

### Problem case

##### azure-deploy.yml

```
extends:
  template: azure-deploy-template.yml
  parameters:
    animals: 
    - 'cat'
    - 'dog'
    complexObject:
    - drink: 'water'
      foods:
      - 'apple'
      - 'banana'
```

##### azure-deploy-template.yml

```
parameters:
- name: animals
  type: object
- name: complexObject
  type: object

jobs:
- job: TestJob
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

  steps:
  - ${{ each o in parameters.complexObject }}:
    - ${{ each f in coalesce(o.foods, parameters.animals) }}:
      - script: echo '${{convertToJson(f)}}'
      - script: echo '${{f}}'
```

This fails with the error:
***Unable to convert from Object to String***

If I remove the last line in `azure-deploy-template.yml`, just the json outputs.
Output:

```
{
  "lit": "apple",
  "style": "",
  "line": "13",
  "col": "5",
  "type": "0"
}
{
  "lit": "banana",
  "style": "",
  "line": "13",
  "col": "5",
  "type": "0"
}
```

Why is the string array being interpreted as this strange complex object?